# How can I return Special Characters in SQL?

Tags: sql, return, substring, character, return-value

I've been searching and I couldnt found exactly what I need.

I have and SQL Server 2008

I have some strings in a table with special characters such as  "!,;:-()" and I'm trying to make a script that could return this characters, BUT ONLY THOSE CHARACTERS (do you get it?)

For example, I have *"Borges, Ricardo"* and I need to return only the ","

Another example, *"Calle 13 Nº 34, Mercedes Bs As ( 6600)"*, and I only need the "º,()"

I dont want to get the letters or numbers.

I wrote this simple script:

**SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%[^A-Za-z0-9 ]%'**

SO I could get all the rows where there is a Special Character like a (,;.:-()&%$...   but I need to RETURN ONLY the special Characters. Get it? No letters, no numbers, only the special characters in the row.

THank you very much for your help!

Comment: What is your exact database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Teradata, etc.)?  We need to know this in order to help you.

Comment: Regex probably but it depends on your actual database.

Comment: Uoops, sory, it SQL Server 2008.!

I just edited the post! THanks!

Comment: Ugh, SQL Server doesn't support regex replace.  As far as I know your only SQL option is using `patindex`.  But it's gonna be pretty slow.

Comment: Thanks!! I tried PATINDEX and I think thats just what I needed!! 
I could make a script that returns the special characters, Now I just need to fix it to find a second o more special characters at the row!

Thank you very much for your help!!!